# Switch to another keyboard language using stock keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages, localization

I have an Xperia (SOL21).

How can I fast switch to another keyboard language, using the default keyboard?

I'm mostly typing in Japanese, but usually swiftly change to Swedish and English (on a non-Android device). How do I do it on Android?

Comment: Which Android version does your phone run?

Comment: It is Android version 4.0.4.

Comment: I got another Android too, a Galaxy SIII, at 4.0.4. I'm unable to do the same thing there as well. It seems like the only languages available are English, Japanese and Korean. Did the makers (Sony and Samsung) deliberately remove all other keyboard languages? I assume Android should support most keyboard languages by default.

Comment: I opened another question regarding default keyboards, as it seems that the devices I have don't have the default keyboards. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40881/install-default-android-keyboard Other answers around here all assume the default keyboard is there.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leaving the stock keyboard and using the [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&feature=search_result). It does  have a language change key that is great for changing inputs, unlike some stock keyboards. I've set up English (QWERTY), English (DVORAK), and Spanish. Its compatible with Android 4.0+.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. That's not to say you are wrong, but some people (like me) came here because they are *trying* to leave the stock keyboard, but fail, because they need to change their language (to English) to enter their wifi password and *install* another keyboard.

Comment: I'd refute your "observation" by noting that OP has said nothing about not being able to access their wifi to install another keyboard app. You can also sideload apps, even without root. Wifi is not strictly a requirement to have new apps installed. OP is only asking for a quick way of switching between keyboards.

Answer (score -1):

To switch to another language, you need to open the keyboard selection menu, where every language will be listed as an individual keyboard (named Android keyboard). This menu is in the notification area (just as another notification, present when the keyboard is visible).