# What needs to be set up in an Android device from another region for a Russian user in Russia, and how?

Tags: settings, localization

We've got a Samsung Galaxy S from another region (China or Korea).

What needs to be set up in it for a Russian user in Russia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Simple things

The obvious group of settings that needs to be changed (simply by selecting the appropriate value) is the interface language, time zone.

### Keyboard

One unexpected difficulty is the input method.

The factory Samsung OS (from another region) doesn't include a Samsung Russian keyboard, nor [does it include the standard Android keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40881/13117) (which might have a Russian keyboard). Further complication: [The standard Android keyboard cannot be installed separately!](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40906/13117)

As a solution, I chose to install [AnySoftKeyboard](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=keyboard&fdid=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard) (which is also available on F-Droid, which guarantees it is free/open-source, can be rebuilt from sources, and has been inspected by more people for not having spying features). Then in its settings menu, I chose to download a Russian pack.

### Mobile networks and internet

For internet to work, one needs to set up an APN (for example, [for Megafon](http://labs.megafon.ru/rel/?hsh=aHR0cDovL2xhYnMubWVnYWZvbi5ydS9kZXYvIzQyOjExMTExNzoxODcyOnNlcnY6Nw==), a Russian mobile operator, one needs to add a new APN with "internet" as the value for the field "APN" -- the only essential field; and select it).

### (Regressions)

(Still, as compared to Samsung Galaxy S sold in Russia, this one has much more unstable connection to the mobile network (loses the connection, i.e., is offline very often). Perhaps, this can be solved by [upgrading the ROM/modem firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44086/13117) from the present Android 2.2 I9000XXJPK (kernel 2.6.32.9) FROYO.XXJPK.)

Comment: It's a good answer, but can be improved with screenshots and examples.

Comment: Interestingly, when [installing CyanogenMod on this device](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd) (cm-10.0.0-galaxysmtd.zip with gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip), no such manual set up had to be done: it was able to connect to Internet over the mobile network already on the first "welcome" screen after the installation (asking to log in to Google), and then it imported the language seting from Google automatically, too.

Comment: @imz Ready mobile network setting is probably a known feature of CyanogenMod -- <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod>: "Features supported by CyanogenMod include native theming support, FLAC audio codec support, a large Access Point Name list, ..."

Comment: The modem firmware that is presently working very bad for us is XXJPK, and--on another device from China or Korea--SPJG2, which also has bad/unstable signal, but not as bad as XXJPK.